# Shorthand for an operation involving matrices, using xor

Tags: matlab, xor

I have 2 matrices

```
A = [a b; c d];
B = [e f; g h];
```

where `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h` are either `0` or `1`.

I want to do

```
[(a*e) xor (b*g) (a*f) xor (b*h);
 (c*e) xor (d*g) (c*f) xor (d*h)];
```

Is there any MATLAB command for this operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using matrix multiplication:

```
result = A*B ==1;
```

Explanation:

Your operation is the same as matrix multiplication except that in matrix multiplication we use `sum` operation instead of `xor` .Here is the matrix multiplication:

```
[(a*e) + (b*g) (a*f) + (b*h);
 (c*e) + (d*g) (c*f) + (d*h)];
```

With `xor` we want to see if two operands are different and if we sum two binary numbers the possible outputs are `[0 1 2]= [0+0 1+0 1+1]` so we can see that only two operands are different if their sum is 1 so we compute the matrix multiplication and check if it equals 1.

And here is a solution using pre-computed linear indexes:

```
result = A([1 1;2 2]) & B([1 3;1 3]) ~= A([3 3;4 4]) & B([2 4;2 4]);
```

Comment: This works well for numerical matrices. Note that if using logical matrices (as one might when dealing with logical statements like this) you will encounter an error trying to do the matrix multiplication without conversion to a numerical type.

Comment: @Wolfie Which version of MATLAB  are you using? [MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html) doesn't  restrict logical data types. Also it works well in Octave.

Comment: I tried `logical(A)*logical(B)` and got an error on 2015b for using non-scalar inputs... this behaviour is odd because `A = logical(A); B = logical(B); A*B` works as expected.

Comment: @Wolfie Neither the former nor the latter works in R2017a. Works in Octave though